# Ошибка 404 при обработке ссылки. Zend Framework

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, zend-framework

Здравствуйте! 
При попытке перейти по ссылке получаю ошибку 404. Подобные ссылки на соседних страницах обрабатываются нормально. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где копать. 
P.S. я не программист

---

```
 function editAction()
{
    global $db;

    $user  = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
    if($user["role"] != "admin") {
        $this->_redirect("/");
    }

    $id = (int) $this->_request->getParam('id', 0);
    $this->view->id = $id;
    if ($id > 0)
    {
        $this->view->title = "Редактирование товара";
        $shop = new Shop();
        $row = $shop->fetchRow('id='.$id);
        if(! $row)
        {
            $exception = new Exception('Страница не найдена', 404);
            $this->getResponse()->setException($exception);
        }
        global $db;
        $this->view->images = $db->select()->from("optsb_shop_images")->where("shop_id=?", $row->id)->order('main DESC')->order('sort ASC')->query()->fetchAll();
        $articles = array();
        $article_rows = $db->select()->from("optsb_articles_rel")->where("element_id=?", $row->id)->where("type='shop'")->query()->fetchAll();
        foreach($article_rows as $article)
        {
            $articles[] = $article["article_id"];
        }
        $this->view->articles_rel = $articles;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->view->title = "Новый товар";
        $row = new stdClass();
        $row->id = 0;
        $row->act = 0;
        $row->sale = 0;
        $row->name = '';
        $row->article = '';
        $row->price = '';
        $row->price_opt = '';
        $row->forum_link = '';
        $row->cat_id = '';
        $row->c = '';
        $row->text = '';
        $this->view->images = array();
        $row->created = time();
        $this->view->articles_rel = array();
    }

    $this->view->articles = $db->select()->from("optsb_articles")->order("created DESC")->query()->fetchAll();
    $this->view->upload_image = true;
    $this->view->row = $row;

    $all_rows = $db->select()->from("optsb_shop_category")->order('sort ASC')->query()->fetchAll();
    foreach($all_rows as $row)
    {
        $rows[$row["parent_id"]][] = $row;
    }
    $this->view->rows = $rows;

    $this->render('admin/shop/edit', 'shop', 'admin');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Товара нет в базе, по этому и 404 ошибка
Код отвечающий за это

```
$row = $shop->fetchRow('id='.$id);
if(! $row) {
    $exception = new Exception('Страница не найдена', 404);
    $this->getResponse()->setException($exception);
}
```